# Question on Inequality in non-Archimedean Valuation/Metric

Tags: number-theory, analysis, p-adic-number-theory

In the book "A Course in $p$ Adic Analysis" by Alain M. Robert, he presents the following theorem.

"Equipped with the $p$ adic metric, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ forms a topological ring that is complete, compact, and metrizable."

The proof of this fact is the following: Since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a topological group under addition (proven before in text), it suffices to show that multiplication is continuous.  Let $x=a+h$ and $y=b+k$ be elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with fixed $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_p$.  Thus,
$$|xy-ab|=|(a+h)(b+k)-ab|=|ak+bh-hk|\le\max(|a|,|b|)(|h|+|k|)+|k||h|$$
which tends to $0$ as $|h|,|k|\to 0$.  This proves continuity in $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$.

However, I am confused on the final inequality.  Specifically, how did he get from
$$|xy-ab|=|(a+h)(b+k)-ab|=|ak+bh-hk|?$$
Using basic arithmetic I thought it should be written as
$$|xy-ab|=|(a+h)(b+k)-ab|=|ak+bh+hk|=|(ak+hk)+bh|=|kx+bh|\le\max(|kx|,|bh|)?$$
Doesn't this provide the same conclusion since this tends to $0$ as $|h|,|k|\to 0$? Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Yes there might be an (inconsequential) sign error in the line you quote. However, in your attempt, I do not see an immediate reason for either you last inequality, nor for the equality right before that.

Comment: The reason for $|(ak+hk)+bh|=|kx+bh|$ is because $(ak+hk)=k(a+h)$ and we let $x=a+h$ earlier in the proof.  The reason  for the final inequality is because the $p$ adic metric is non-Archimedean, so we have $|x+y|\le \max(|x|,|y|)$.

Comment: Ok to the first, but $kx \neq kh$.

Comment: Fixed, you are right, it should have been $kx$ in the final inequality.  Does my argument still hold?

Comment: I guess so, although to show that $\lvert kx \rvert \to 0$ for $\lvert k \rvert, \lvert h \rvert \to 0$ is maybe not simpler than the original argument.